# Failed usb port

Tags: windows-7, usb

What can I do to revive a failed usb port 
I have an older pavilion desktop that only has the ports on front working on the front of the tower. None of the rear USB port function.

Comment: More details would be needed - the exact model would help, as might pictures of the faulty and good ports.   This could be a hardware issue, or a cabling (inside the PC) issue or a driver issue.

Comment: Or use a hub, preferably powered.

Answer (score 1):

The ports on the back are connected directly to the motherboard, there is nothing short of a new motherboard that can fix that.

The ports on the front can be replaced because they connect to the motherboard via cable.  However, it only works on physical damage, and not the controller chip has gone bad.

Thankfully add-in card like this are plentiful. This card is PCI for older  units.

https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=48&gclid=CjwKCAjw4uXaBRAcEiwAuAUz8KED0YXLOgh_8qmC2_aervRI0cf7m_QXUI6OIAFkWsoiPjDFDo7b_RoCv5oQAvD_BwE

If you have a pci-e slot there are litterally hunderds of options on amazon to choose from.
[image]